# Xamarin forms Switch Toggled event fires automatically whenever navigate to that page

Tags: user-interface, xamarin, xamarin.forms, switchcontrol

I am using Xamarin forms switch inside collection view like the below.

```
  <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding SwitchStatus}">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <StackLayout HeightRequest="100" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Spacing="30">
                                <Switch x:Name="mySwitch" IsToggled="{Binding State}"> 
                                    <Switch.Behaviors>
                                        <prism:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="Toggled" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Command="{Binding BindingContext.UpdateCommand,Source={x:Reference myPage}}"/>
                                    </Switch.Behaviors>
                                </Switch>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

            </CollectionView>
```

Toggled event of the Switch getting fired automatically whenever I navigate to that page because of IsToggled Binding property set. Is there any way to restrict Switch Toggled event when the user not manually triggered?

To be more clear, I have attached my [sample here](https://github.com/JayramJai/SwitchToggledPrism).

Followed prism MVVM, EventToCommandBehavior I should follow all these.

Help me with the sample code would be greatful.

Answer (score 1):

> . Is there any way to restrict Switch Toggled event when the user not manually triggered?

I'm afraid there is no method to achieve it .

First , [Check the source code of Switch](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/5.0.0/Xamarin.Forms.Core/Switch.cs) .

```
public static readonly BindableProperty IsToggledProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IsToggled), typeof(bool), typeof(Switch), false, propertyChanged: (bindable, oldValue, newValue) =>
        {
            ((Switch)bindable).Toggled?.Invoke(bindable, new ToggledEventArgs((bool)newValue));
            ((Switch)bindable).ChangeVisualState();
        }, defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay);
```

It is clear that `Toggled` event would trigger if the `IsToggled` property changes .

In other word ,no matter we toggle the switch manually or changes `IsToggled` programmatically ,
`Toggled` will be triggerd , and then `EventToCommandBehavior` will works after that .

Comment: I agree with your point but that doesn't answer my question. I achieved it with my own logic. Thanks.

Comment: Hi there, would you mind sharing how you fixed? I have the same issue.